# How can I remove a element from a list even though there are equal elements inside?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
list = [1,7,2,8,9,2,7,9,2,8,2]
```

How can I remove two of the "2" without removing the others?

Comment: You could call `.remove(2)` twice.

Comment: Create a new list, and in a `for` loop, copy over just the elements you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the one(s) you want to delete and use the function pop(index) to delete it/them.

Exemple:

```
your_list.pop(5) # Delete the 5th element of your list
```

Here's a little doc: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop

Answer (score 0):

This should work by removing an `i` element `n` times from a list `arr`.

```py
arr = [1,7,2,8,9,2,7,9,2,8,2]

def remove(arr, i, n = 1):
    for _ in range(n):
        arr.remove(i)

remove(arr, 2, 3)
print(arr)
```